# Denoising Autoencoders weights at test time

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders, dropout

When using masking noise whilst training Denoising Autoencoders should weights be increased at test time proportional to the masking rate, as in Dropout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming the noise has the same nature (ie. setting each input to 0 with some probability `p`), the same reasoning applies and you should increase the weights at test time. Conversely, you could reduce them during training, which is not exactly equivalent because of the non-linearities, but in practice seems to behave well too.

However, if the noise is just Gaussian noise added to the inputs, then you should not change the weights at test time since Gaussian noise does not affect the scale of the inputs.