# Do weights learned from pre-training using a Denoising Autoencoder need rescaling when using dropout in complete NN?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, restricted-boltzmann-machine, dropout, pre-training

I have a question related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146558/denoising-autoencoders-weights-at-test-time) question.

I am using a denoising autoencoder for pre-training of a neural network for dimensionality reduction. I want to use the weights learned in the pre-training step for finetuning with dropout. Should I still rescale the learned weights from pre-training in the initialization even if the denoising level is chosen to be the same as the dropout rate?

In detail:
I have a network like this: 1000-100-10-100-1000.
I use pre-training: 1000-100-1000; 100-10-100. Denoising level 0.3. Learning W1, W2.
The full network is initialized with W1-W2-W2.T-W1.T. In training this network using a dropout rate of 0.3 would I still need to employ the technique of rescaling the weights from pre-training as in [this paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, you should scale up the weights at test time (or scale them down during training). See my answer to the [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237762/109561).